# あるオブジェクト、型を限定したキー名を指定する型の書き方について

Tags: typescript

TypeScriptの型の指定で困っています。以下のような `toMap` という関数でコンパイルを通すことができません。

```js
const toMap = <T extends {}>(items: T[], key: keyof T) => {
    const map = {};
    items.forEach((item) => {
        map[item[key]] = item; // ここでエラー
    });
    return map;
}

const data = [
    { id: '1', value: { foo: 'bar' } },
    { id: '2', value: { hoge: 'piyo' } },
];

toMap(data, 'id'); // => { '1': { ... }, '2': { ... } }
```

`<T extends {}>(items: T[], key: any): { [key: string]: T }` とでも妥協すればいいのはわかるのですが、 `any` を使わずに解決したいと思っています。

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#example-2 の `FunctionPropertyNames<T>` を参考に `type StringPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never }[keyof T];` を定義し、 `<T extends {}>(items: T[], key: StringPropertyNames<T>)` としたのも駄目でした。

Answer (score 1):

keyで指定されたプロパティがstringである型の配列を受け取る関数という形では書けました。

```js
function toMap<K extends string, T extends {[I in K]: string}>(items: T[], key: K) {
    const map: { [index: string]: T } = {};

    items.forEach((item: E) => {
        const id = item[key];
        map[id] = item;
    });
    return map;
}
```